# Login fails and getting Runtime Error when submitting password of a specific pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC for a project, Everything works fine. Recently someone reported that if he tried to login to the interface with this password `J&Mg<in5` the interface showed error page I mean not even the custom 500 error page which we have configured and works otherwise.

[image]

I have elmah configured on this project, no error is shown there too.

I little more investigation showed that all password of type, examples below

- `<ee`
- `<fd`
- `<reee`

i.e "<" followed by any character gave this error.

Why is this error coming, and how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the [request validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that triggers in this case. Try disabling it and see if it helps. Also, try looking at the event log, it should contain a bit more useful details on the matter.

Hope this helps.